# npm packages to dump a domain model of a codebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, entity-relationship

im looking at a large codebase and am wondering if there are any tools to dump the `models/` of the codebase so I can visually look at all the entities and how they are tied to one another

I am looking for an output that is akin to an entity relationship diagram that shows relationships between models

Is there such a tool?

*edit:*

- the codebase is a nodejs monolith written in es6 (no typescript)
- also, the DB used is Mongo and the library is mongoose

---

the folder structure is something like

```
root
  - models
    - model1
    - model2
  - controllers
  - view
  - ...
```

Comment: Please provide details of the code base - what is in the `models` directory, what (if any) library generated those models?

Comment: hey @LeeGoddard thanks for the questions, I have made some edits
also to respond to your query about the "generated models", they were hand coded

Comment: So a library to visualize the data? Something like Mongo Charts...?

Comment: no @LeeGoddard more like an ER diagram that shows the various fields in models and the relationship between them

Comment: That's the prhrase I couldn't remember. If you add that to your question, it may help.